# Symbol of system of equations

Tags: equation-solving, syntax, symbols, built-in-symbols, education

I'm wondering if there is a way to use the symbol (the left curly bracket) of a system of equations. So far I found only the following "symbol":

[image]

I need to remove the two conditions.

---

EDIT2: the Basic Typesetting section of Mathematica 11.2 is:

[image]

As you can see the symbols on the same line of the symbol of the system of equations can be used to perform calculations.

[image]

Comment: you mean using paletts?  you can use the basic typesetting, it has one.  screen shot ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUgNt.png)

Comment: Hello @Nasser yes it's the one in your figure. Which Mathematica version do you have? Btw maybe you can give me that symbol in this way: put the symbol in a notebook and share it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: It is under "basic typesetting" it should be on your version, its been there for ever, I am using V 13. Screen shot ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6UVfx.png)   see if you can find it under Palettets menu.  I just looked at V 11.3 I have and it is there also.

Comment: @Nasser I found it. Thank you a lot. I tried to solve a simple system x+y=1 and y=2, but I got Syntax::sntxi: Incomplete expression; more input is needed . How can I overcome this?

Comment: I do not use Palettes myself. I am old fashioned. I prefer to just type using plain text code. Why not just type `eq1 = x + y == 1 ; eq2 = y == 2; Solve[{eq1, eq2}, {x, y}]` ? This gives `{{x -> -1, y -> 2}}`

Comment: @Nasser I'd like to learn how to use palettes. Until now I used the InputForm. I'll post another question about that. Thank you a lot for your willingness.

Comment: @Gennaro Arguzzi  I guess you mixed up two different things. **One thing** is how one solves a system of equations. This way is demonstrated above in the comment of Nasser. No palette is needed. **The second thing** is absolutely different. It is how one writes down a text containing formulas, graphics, and so on (for example, a paper), such that it looks traditionally. That is, the same way one sees such a text in, say, a textbook. **It is in this case, that pallets are very useful**. I guess, yours is the first case, is it right?

Comment: Hi @AlexeiBoulbitch sorry, I just read your comment. Can you tell me how to use it please? I'd like to solve for example x+y=1 and y=2. If possible can you reply on my new question please? This one is about how to write the symbol of the system of equations, instead the new one is about how to use it.

Answer (score 4):

**One thing is how one solves a system of equations**. This way is demonstrated above in the comment of Nasser. No palette is needed.
Here adding small explanations, I repeat what @Nasser has already written in the comment.

1. In Mma one writes an equation using the doubled equality symbol. That is `==`, rather than `=`.
2. The function for solving algebraic equations and their systems is `Solve`. For example, in your case, the correct syntax is

   Solve[{x + y == 1, y == 2}, {x, y}]

which returns the result:

```
    (*  {{x -> -1, y -> 2}}  *)
```

Alternatively, you can use the way Nasser has written in the comment:

```
eq1 = x + y == 1 ; 
eq2 = y == 2; 
Solve[{eq1, eq2}, {x, y}]
```

returning the same. Try it.

Further details find please in Menu/Help/WolframDocumentation/Solve
There are lots of examples there, and you will be able to learn the syntax by analogy.

**The second thing is absolutely different. It is how one writes down a text (such as a paper, a report, ...), containing formulas**, such that it looks traditionally. That is, the same way one sees such a text in, say, a textbook. It is in this case, that palettes are useful, though not necessary.

Below, one can see an image of a system of equations from one of my recent notebooks containing a scientific report.

[image]

This I show only as an example to demonstrate, how such a formula can eventually look like.

Now, let us create a scientific text step by step

**Step 1**: Choosing a StyleSheet

1. Let us open a new notebook
2. Go to Menu/Format/Stylesheet. A drop-down menu will pop up. Choose one of the following: Article/JournalArticle or Article/Preprint or Book or Report.

Each of them has its own style of typing the text and the equations, but also some peculiarities of working with, and you should choose one of your likings by trial and error. My preferred style is Article/JournalArticle. I will further describe this style, but working with any of them differs only slightly.

**Step 2**: Making Title, text and input cells

Assuming that you have already selected the JournalArticle StyleSheet,

1. Put the cursor in the first line and then go to Menu/Help/Format/Style and select Title. Type "A title" in the first line.
2. Put the cursor in the next line and then go to Menu/Help/Format/Style and select Section. Type "A section"
3. Put the cursor in the next line and then go to Menu/Help/Format/Style and select Text. Type "some text"
4. Put the cursor in the next line and then go to Menu/Help/Format/Style and select Input. Type `Solve[{x + y == 1, y == 2}, {x, y}]`. Evaluate it.

**Step 3**: Making "Display formula" cell

1. Put the cursor in the next line and then go to Menu/Help/Format/Style and select "Equation" or "EquationNumbered". In some other StyleSheets the same may be called "DisplayFormula" or "DisplayFormulaNumbered." Type `a+b=c`.
2. Let us now make an EquationNumbered cell containing a system of equations.

a) Put the cursor in the next line and then go to Menu/Help/Format/Style and select "EquationNumbered".

b) Place the cursor into this line and type the left curly brace "{".

c) press Ctrl+Enter. You get a left curly brace with two placeholders behind it. Fill them in by `x + y = 1` and `y=2`. Done.

Alternatively, you can do the same using the palettes:

a) Put the cursor in the next line and then go to Menu/Help/Format/Style and select "EquationNumbered", and in this line type the left curly brace "{".

b) Open Menu/Palettes/WritingAssistent and select the button containing two placeholders arranged in the column.

c) Fill them in by `x + y = 1` and `x=2`. Done.

**Fine-tuning**: if the left curly brace looks not large enough one can increase its size.
To do this,

a) select the left curly brace. Take care to only select the left curly brace, but not the expressions behind it

b) Go to Menu/Format/Size and from the drop-down menu select the greater size of your liking.

[image]

That's how it should look like in the JournalArticle StyleSheet.

**Comment 1**: Note that in formula (3) I increased the left curly brace to 16 pts, while in (4) left it as it initially was, that is, 12 pts. This is up to you.

**Comment 2**: Be aware of the fact that **each** of the above operations has a hotkey, and therefore, everything can be done rather fast.

Have fun!

Comment: thank you for your very detailed answer. I know that you can use symbol also to do calculations and not only for aesthetic reasons. In fact If I click on the symbol of the square root in the Basic Typesetting and I write 4 under the symbol, the result is 2 after I click Shift+Enter. I'd like to use the symbol of the system of equations in the same manner. Can you tell me how to do it please?

Comment: It does not work this way. Some of the items of the palettes (such as the square root, integral, derivative, and more) correspond to the Mma syntax, some others do not. The latter items are only for the text formating. The left curly brace belongs to this latter case. Such is a syntax, and one cannot and should not violate it.

Comment: in the same row of the symbol of the system of equations there is the symbol of the matrix. Why I can do the matrix multiplication by using that symbol. It seems strange that I cannot use only the symbol of the system of equations.

Comment: I strongly recommend you to learn the syntax.

Comment: is there any documentation which says that I cannot use palette to solve a system ofequations? I know how to solve it by using the Solve command, but I'd like to learn this other way just for fun.